# Не работает загрузчик файлов php

Tags: php, ubuntu, input

Очень нужна ваша помощь. Дело в том, что у меня не работает загрузчик файлов. У меня есть простенький php скрипт, который загружает несколько файлов из multiple input в одну папку. Проблема в том, что этот скрипт у меня работает некорректно. Он загружает только последний файл, а остальные игнорирует. Но вся загвоздка в том, что у моих друзей если им отправить архив, то у них все работает. Я не понимаю в чем проблема. Я даже пытался залить его на хост и там он не работает. Я полагаю дело в правах, но я уже пытался поставить все права, которые нужны, но все равно ничего. Если вардампунть $_FILES после загрузки, то он выдает это:

```
array(1) { ["file"]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(8) "название файла" } ["type"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(9) "image/png" } ["tmp_name"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(14) "/tmp/phpTTDRlb" } ["error"]=> array(1) { [0]=> int(0) } ["size"]=> array(1) { [0]=> int(1923) } } }
```

Если дело в правах, то как дать права на загрузку и т.д. моему серверу, а не только мне?

Вот скрипт

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

     $countfiles = count($_FILES['file']['name']);
     var_dump($_FILES);

        for($i=0;$i<$countfiles;$i++){

        $filename = $_FILES['file']['name'][$i];
        $ext = array_pop(explode(".", $filename));



        $randFileName = md5(time().rand(0,9999).$filename).".".$ext;

        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i],'../photoes/'.$randFileName);
        var_dump($_FILES);

     }

}

?>
```

Comment: Ну так у вас в `$_FILES` один файл, он и загружается. Что не так то? Приведите пример, где файлов несколько и какие из них загрузились, а какие нет.

Comment: Данный вардамп это после загрузки как раз нескольких файлов, я не знаю как, но видит он только последний файл

Comment: Проблема на стороне html, а не php

Comment: Но у моих друзей-то все работает

Comment: И js все нормально видит, я написал на jquery скрипт, который выводит загруженные в него изображения и там все нормально работает

Comment: всё-же попробуйте поискать ошибку до или в момент отправки формы. ну или код приведите - может люди увидят.